# Manipulating 100gb Table

Tags: csv, large-files

I have a particular dataset in tsv format seperated by tabs that is one big txt file of around 100gb (Somewhere around 255 million rows). I have to filter and extract relevant rows so I can easily work on them. So far, I know that Excel can't handle that many rows, and familliar text editors can't open or very painful to work with tables. I've tried LogParser, a 36 mins query gave me a csv output but unfortunately exported number of rows are way below what I guess is present in the data. Also I get some parsing errors and some columns in the exported sets are shifted. Do you have any other alternatives? Maybe can I somehow turn the data into an SQL database? Is it possible?

Comment: You need a simple script, PHP script for example, which would iterate this file line by line and export this data to your database. For every row that does not match other ones (shifted/corrupted etc.) would dump it to other file so that records can be imported later on with another script.

Comment: what tools do you have at hand, what are you familiar with? if you are experienced in python, NumPy can work with large data files pretty well.

Comment: I did infact give some thoughts on writing a python script. I have basic python knowledge but never worked with NumPy before. Thanks, I'll look into it. I guess I was a bit more concentrated on ready solutions.